# How to store output of an algorithm into a new array

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

```
value1 = 0 and value2 = 0 with weight 0

value1 = 1 and value2 = 6 with weight 5

value1 = 2 and value2 = 4 with weight 4

value1 = 3 and value2 = 3 with weight 2

value1 = 5 and value2 = 2 with weight 4

value1 = 5 and value2 = 7 with weight 6

value1 = 8 and value2 = 5 with weight 6
```

How will i store this output into a new array (different array for value1, value2 and weight) and compare them

Comment: Doesn't sound too hard. What have you tried? Have you read something like [this]?(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. You're not sure how to create 3 arrays? You want to update an array while retaining old values somewhere? What is the "output"? You've just described 3 sets of values. What's the input and what's the output?

Comment: that is the output i got from my previous algorithm and i want to store them into a new array so that i can compare them. So that I will get the values from valu1 and value2 that are not completely dominated by the other

Comment: Change your output format to something that is easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean containing the value1, value2 and weight like this

```
public class AlgoItem {
    private Integer value1;
    private Integer value2;
    private Integer weight;
    // Setter and getter
}
```

And use a Collection to store it (you can use a HashSet or a ArrayList for implementation of a Collection)

So your method will return a Collection of AlgoItem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two dimensional array

```
        int[][] values = new int[][] {{ 0, 0, 0}, {1, 6, 5}, {2,4,4}};
```

The first array is an array of arrays containing your 3 values.

This is the simple and dirty way.  I would recommend making an Object which holds all 3 of your values and then making a list of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you're problem is. Perhaps you should show us what you've tried that didn't work.

```
int[] value1=new int[7];
int[] value2=new int[7];
int[] weight=new int[7];

value1[0]=0
value2[0]=0;
weight[0]=0;

value1[1]=1;
value2[1]=6;
weight[1]=5;

value1[2]=2;
value2[2]=4;
weight[2]=4;

... etc ...
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I store tha array like this : int val1[] = { 0, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8}; int val2[] = { 0, 6, 4, 3, 2, 7, 5}; And now I want to compare the values in val1 and values in val2, I tried this algorithm but it does not work fine: for(int j = 0; j <= len1; j++)
  {
   for(int k = 0; k <= len2; k++)
   {
    if(val1[j] >= val1[j+1] && val2[k] >= val2[k+1])
    {
     System.out.println("Value1 = " + val1[j] + " Value2 = " + val2[k]);
    }
   }
  }

Comment: When you say you are trying to compare val1 to val2 ... Your example code matches every entry in val1 to every entry in val2, i.e. 7 x 7 = 49 matches, but then doesn't compare val1 to val2, but rather compares each val1 entry to the following val1 entry, and each val2 entry to the following val2 entry. And by the way if len1 is the number of entries in val1, this won't work, because you're running j up to len1, but the last entry in val1 is len1-1. Normally a loop through an array should be for (int j=0;j<val1.lenth;++j) -- note "<", not "<=". Also, comparing val1[j] to val1[j+1] means ...

Comment: ... that j must stop at the entry before the last, or you'll be trying to compare the last entry to the entry after the last, and of course there is no "entry after the last". But really the issue here is, What do you mean when you say you want to compare val1 to val2? Do you just want to check if val1[0]==val2[0], val1[1]==val2[1], etc? Or is the comparison more complex?